# How to convert UInt64 to Int64?

Tags: compiler-errors, swift, type-conversion, numeric-conversion

The second argument in this function call:

```
dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC)
```

causes the compiler error:

```
'UInt64' is not convertible to 'Int64'
```

**Swift Reference**:

```
func dispatch_time(when: dispatch_time_t, delta: Int64) -> dispatch_time_t

var NSEC_PER_SEC: UInt64 { get } /* nanoseconds per second */
```

Answer (score 0):

See: [How do you cast a UInt64 to an Int64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24538954/242933) That question doesn't show up when googling the compiler error: `'UInt64' is not convertible to 'Int64'`