# How do i encode a PersistentID for a song using NSCoder in Swift 3

Tags: ios, persistence

This is my first time using NSCoder and there used to be a method called encodeInteger but it seems to have vanished in Swift 3 and the docs don't seem to help.

It maybe that the confusion lies in the difference between Int and UInt64. Are they the same?

Should i be using a NSKeyedArchiver and if so how does that work to comply with NSCoding?

Here's before with the error:
[image]
And after without an error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use NSNumber and encode it as an object? It'd look like this:

```
let bigNumber: UInt64 = /* 123 */
let number = NSNumber(value: bigNumber)

// Encoding it just like a String    
coder.encode(number, forKey: "BigNumberKey")

// Decoding and using the property uint64Value from NSNumber to get the UInt64 back
if let object = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "BigNumberKey") as? NSNumber {
    let decodedBigNumber = object.uint64Value
}
```

If that's a requirement for some reason, NSCoder supports the [encoding of Int64](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscoder/1410440-encodeint64) (and you could cast it, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538954/how-do-you-cast-a-uint64-to-an-int64)).

---

The change from `encodeInteger` to just `encode` is part of [SE-0005](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md) (which affected a lot of different classes; `UIColor.blueColor()` is now `UIColor.blue()`, for instance).

Comment: Worked perfectly